# Workflow in developing an EnderJS library component

Tags: javascript

I'm developing a code module that will become an Ender library component. I have the source in a /src directory (the component .js and an ender.js bridge file). As I develop the code, I want to test the code -- iteratively. Which requires that I build the actual ender.js library file.

The problem is that running the "ender" (bin) command

```
$ ender build myComponent
```

expects the myComponent to be an npm installable/updatable module, located in ./node_moudules. But I want ender to build from the ./src directory.

I know the docs say that one can specify a relative path, as in:

```
$ ender ../path/to/myComponent
```

but I can't quite get this to work.... I assume I need a package.json that refers to the source files, so, I create a /build directory and put a package.json in there that has very little info, just:

```
{
    "ender": "../src/ender.js",
    "main": "../src/doml.js",
    "name": "doml",
}
```

("doml" is the name of my library component).

But when I try executing:

$ ender ./build/doml

I get the message:

```
something went wrong install your packags!
```

which is generated by the install method of ender-js's ender.npm.js file. So... something is terribly amiss because I don't want npm to install anything, I want ender to build from source that I'm specifying.

Clearly I am confused... please help clarify for me how development workflow can or should be organized.

(please note, I wanted to create an ender-js tag for this question, but I don't have sufficient reputation on StackOverflow to create a new tag.)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you're having difficulties with this :(

When you specify a local path as in `$ender build ./my/micro/lib` -- npm is *still* used to install your package.

You can actually install npm packages in a simliar way... try `$npm install ./my/npm/package`

Anyways... here's a checklist for what you need to get it working:

- a directory which inclues a package.json (at it's root)
- the package.json needs to be a valid npm package...

so something like this:

```
{
  "name": "blamo",
  "description": "a thing that blams the o's",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "homepage": "http://blamo-widgets.com",
  "authors": ["Mr. Blam", "Miss O"],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/fake-account/blamo.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "klass": "*"
  }
  "main": "./src/project/blamo.js",
  "ender": "./src/exports/ender.js"
}
```

- a path to this directory (which will be used like: `$ender build ./my/path`

So hopefully that works! If you're stil stuck, you could also check out the ender forum here -- http://enderjs.com/

Comment: \@fat: thanks for the detailed answer... but my question wasn't clear enough... I'm trying to run ender in the directory where I am building an ender component. I run "ender build" and ender knows to build with ender-js and "." -- the problem is that ender-file's logic finds the package.json in the current directory, but then later looks to find it again in node_modules. 

I have forked ender on GitHub and made some minor changes that make this work. Please see: https://convore.com/ender-js/developing-ender-components/

Comment: ahh... inception style. You're right that won't work (because npm will refuse to install a package that you're in...)

Comment: Anyways... It's actually a pretty straightforward fix. I'll try to push something tonight :)